# move marker and update place in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps, And in a textfield you can type a place and then you will see a marker on the google maps with the coordinates. You can also move the maker and then the coordinates in the info box will be updated. But how to update also the place name in the textfield? Thank you.

This is the jquery script:

```
var map;

function initMap() {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var startaddress = $('#form_inp19').val();  

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': startaddress }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            startLocationMap = results[0].geometry.location;
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: startLocationMap
            });

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
                geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
           });
        } else {
            alert('Place doesnt exist on the map: ' + status);
        }
        if (typeof google.maps == 'undefined') {
            /* custom functions to alert the user to the error */
            return 0;
        }
    });

}//end function initMap

$(document).ready(function () {

    if (typeof google.map == 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  mapOptions);
});


function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

var marker;
var infowindow;
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
        infowindow.close();
    }

    if (typeof marker != 'undefined') {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: "Drag me!"
            });           

        } else {
            alert('Place doesnt exist on the map: ' + status);
        }

        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'            


        });       

        $(".geolocation_lat ").val(marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)) //= marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
        $(".geolocation_long ").val(marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6))       

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.close();
            }
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'
            });
            $(".geolocation_lat ").val(event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)); //= marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
            $(".geolocation_long ").val(event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));

            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I have it now like this:

```
var map;

function initMap() {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var startaddress = $('#form_inp19').val();  

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': startaddress }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            startLocationMap = results[0].geometry.location;
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 12,
                center: startLocationMap
            });

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function () {
                geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
           });
        } else {
            alert('Place doesnt exist on the map: ' + status);
        }
        if (typeof google.maps == 'undefined') {
            /* custom functions to alert the user to the error */
            return 0;
        }
    });

}//end function initMap

$(document).ready(function () {

    if (typeof google.map == 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
  mapOptions);
});


function toggleBounce() {
    if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    } else {
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    }
}

var marker;
var infowindow;

//Added
function geocodePosition(pos) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        latLng: pos
    }, function (responses) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('address') = responses[0].formatted_address;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('address') = 'Cannot determine address at this location.';
        }
    });
}


function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
        infowindow.close();
    }

    if (typeof marker != 'undefined') {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }

    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: resultsMap,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                title: "Drag me!"
            });



        } else {
            alert('Place doesnt exist on the map: ' + status);
        }



        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'            


        });       

        $(".geolocation_lat ").val(marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6)) //= marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
        $(".geolocation_long ").val(marker.getPosition().lng().toFixed(6))       

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
            geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.close();
            }
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<p>Marker Location:'
                    + 'lat: ' + event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)
                    + ', '
                    + 'lng: ' + event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6)
                    + '</p>'
            });
            $(".geolocation_lat ").val(event.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)); //= marker.getPosition().lat().toFixed(6);
            $(".geolocation_long ").val(event.latLng.lng().toFixed(6));

            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        });

        infowindow.open(map, marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
            if (typeof infowindow != 'undefined') {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    });


}
```

But I get the error:

> 'geocoder' is undefined

I only get this error:

> Cannot assign to a function result

```
document.getElementById('address') = responses[0].formatted_address;
```

I see the address: `responses[0].formatted_address  "Belle van Zuylenlaan 23-24, 2642 Pijnacker, Nederland"`

But how to get only the place name in the textfield?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dragend listener,

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
```

and

```
function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById('yourTextBoxId').value=responses[0].formatted_address;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('yourTextBoxId').value='Cannot determine address at this location.';
    }
  });
}
```

[Here is a working example (puts the address received from the reverse geocoder in the infowindow)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reversegeocoding-simple.html)

Comment: oh put geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); before geocoder.geocode({

Comment: u missed .value, ie document.getElementById('address').value=""

Comment: Yes, Thank you. It works now(  $("#address").val(responses[3].formatted_address);). But how to get only the place name, so without address and postal code? Thank you